# Messages fetched from custom domains through Gmail webmail client are not assigned labels

Tags: gmail, pop3, webmail

I added an account, me@mydomain.com, to be checked along with my personal Gmail account through the Gmail web client. I did so following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289) with the settings provided by my web host (email provider).

At first, I thought it wasn't working at all because the messages (that I confirmed were being delivered to that account) were not appearing in my Gmail inbox or under the me@mydomain.com label.

Eventually I found them under All Mail, which if I understand correctly, means they are not being given any label at all.

As a point of reference, I am successfully doing this with a different account, me@my-other-domain.com, that I set up a couple years ago. It's a different domain, but under the same hosting account and is configured with identical settings (with the exception of login info). I'm confused.

I'm guessing I can set up a filter to route the message to the right place, but I'm curious as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: did you tell it to archive (skip the inbox) and did you assign it a label?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - I did not tell it to skip the inbox. And I assigned it the default label named after the account. I also tried assigning it a few other existing labels. No luck with any of it.